React Admin : A component suspended while responding to synchronous input. This will cause the UI to be replaced with a loading indicator
A component suspended while responding to synchronous input. This will cause the UI to be replaced with a loading indicator. To fix, updates that suspend should be wrapped with startTransition.
i found this error in tabbed form
const ProductCreate = () => (
  <Create>
    <TabbedForm toolbar={<PostEditToolbar />} defaultValues={{ sales: 0 }}>
      <TabbedForm.Tab label="Details">
        <ProductEditDetails />
      </TabbedForm.Tab>
      <TabbedForm.Tab
        label="Variation"
        disabled
        path="details"
        sx={{ maxWidth: "40em" }}
      ></TabbedForm.Tab>
      <TabbedForm.Tab label="Attribute" path="description">
        <AutocompleteInput
          multiple
          choices={[
            { _id: "tech", label: "Tech" },
            { _id: "lifestyle", label: "Lifestyle" },
            { _id: "people", label: "People" },
          ]}
        />
        <RichTextInput source="description" label="" />
      </TabbedForm.Tab>
    </TabbedForm>
  </Create>
);


i was unable to find this issue as it comes when i  navigate to create form on very first time after login.
i am expecting suggestion and solution

I see nothing in the code you shared that explains this error. However it is likely the issue lies elsewhere in your codebase. You should consider sharing a complete project reproducing the issue, for example by forking this codesandbox.
